# Debugging web application causes Google captcha

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, captcha

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, but I am seeing an annoying issue when debugging ASP MVC applications on visual studio.

After pressing F5, Firefox opens and everything works normally, but after doing this a few times, when I try searching anything on google from the same network I am presented with multiple captchas (usually 2 at a time).

It seems that Google thinks there is some suspicious activity going on on my computer, but of course everything is just fine.

I am still able to search normally through Chrome, IE etc.

Has anyone else expereienced this issue? If so is there perhaps an option within VS or in my browser to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you share the screen shots about the multiple captchas in your question? Did you get this issue if you just run your app using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", whether all Web apps have this issue or just the specific one? As you said that you research anything on google, do you mean that you have stopped the web app debugging, and then research something using the Google site with the Firefox browser? If other browsers work well, I think it would be related to the Firefox itself.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I have not tried `start without debugging`, but I have had this issue with multiple apps in the past. I also remember getting the same problem when using internet explorer. When I search for the issue I have to use a different browser to the one that was used to debug the app (I still can't search in FFeven after debugging)

Comment: Could you share a screen shot about the result in your side? Before you debug the app again, please clean the cache, and then debug the app, or research anything, how about the result? Actually I remember that I got the research issue before just using the browser itself, but I remember that it is related to google research(if you search many site, it will share a captchas or others) like this one: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1011990. But I didn't find this issue during debug web apps.

Comment: If you get any latest information, please feel free to let me know, my understanding is that it was not the real VS debugging issue, it was related to the Google research in browser.